# Regex to get two strings from single string given as range

Tags: regex

I've got a string like this: `$149.00 - $165.00`

Now I want to write two regex expressions.
One regex expression to return the string `149.00` and other to return `165.00`.

How this can be done?
I tried framing it, but problem is `$` symbolise end of string, so not able to think how to get them.

Comment: Why not write 1 regex to get both values at once in 2 capture groups? And more importantly: what have you tried? What is the programming language/regex flavor?

Comment: This might work: \$\d+(?:\.\d+)?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
/([\\d.]+)/g
```

[**Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/nB2gC6/1)

Comment: I want in two different strings. Not in single string

Comment: Which programming language you were using

Answer (score 0):

Here is a java example as well.

```
    package testHomeWork;

    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class Assignment3e
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            String text = "$149.00 - $165.00";

            String patternString1 = "(\\$.*)\\s+-\\s+(\\$.*)";

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString1);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

            while (matcher.find())
            {
                System.out.println("value1: " + matcher.group(1) + " | value2:" + matcher.group(2));
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is a regular expression example. Note the two capture groups.  I don't know what language your using but most of them have something similar.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

line = "$149.00 - $165.00"

matchObj = re.match( r'(\$.*)\s+-\s+(\$.*)', line, re.M|re.I)

val1 = matchObj.group(1);
val2 = matchObj.group(2);

print "val 1 = %s, val 2 = %s" % ( val1, val2 )
```

Does it have to be a regular expression?  In this case you can use split or split and trim if there is always a dash and a variable amount of white space.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

input = "$149.00 - $165.00"

(value1, value2) = input.split(" - ")
print "value 1 = %s, value2 = %s" % ( value1, value2)
```

Comment: I added a regex example above.